# How to get absolute position of an Element in WP8 and use it to move that element on a new location

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8

How to get absolute position of an Element in WP8 and use it to move that element on a new location

I am trying to move an image using taps on the screen using following code and having an unexpected behavior.

```
        private void SetGame()
    {
        ScreenWidth = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
        ScreenHeight = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;

        var transform = littleMan.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);
        System.Windows.Point absolutePosition = transform.Transform(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));

        manLocY = absolutePosition.Y; //vert
        manLocX = absolutePosition.X; //hori

        leftControlArea = (ScreenWidth / 2);
        rightControlArea = (ScreenWidth / 2); // answer to the screen width;
        topControlArea = (ScreenHeight / 3);
        bottomControlArea = (ScreenHeight / 3) * 2; // answer to the screen height

        littleManWidth = littleMan.ActualWidth;
        littleManHeight = littleMan.ActualHeight;

    }

    private void MoveLittleMan(Vector2 tappedWhere)
    {
        double tapX, tapY;
        tapX = tappedWhere.X; // represent where user tapped on screen width wise
        tapY = tappedWhere.Y; // represent where user tapped on screen height wise


        if(tapY <= topControlArea)
        {
            // move top
            Debug.WriteLine("Move TOP - X: " + tapX + " - Y: " + tapY);
            if (manLocY > littleManHeight)
            {
                manLocY = manLocY - skippingSteps;
                Canvas.SetTop(littleMan, manLocY);
            }
        }

        else if(tapY >= bottomControlArea)
        {
            //move bottom
            Debug.WriteLine("Move BOTTOM - X: " + tapX + " - Y: " + tapY);
            if (manLocY < (ScreenHeight - littleManHeight))
            {
                manLocY = manLocY + skippingSteps;
                Canvas.SetTop(littleMan, manLocY);
            }
        }

        else if (tapX <= leftControlArea && tapY > topControlArea && tapY < bottomControlArea)
        { 
            //move left
            Debug.WriteLine("Move LEFT - X: " + tapX + " - Y: " + tapY);
            if (manLocX > littleManWidth)
            {
                manLocX = manLocX - skippingSteps;
                Canvas.SetLeft(littleMan, manLocX);
            }
        }
        else if (tapX > rightControlArea && tapY > topControlArea && tapY < bottomControlArea)
        { 
            //move right
            Debug.WriteLine("Move RIGHT - X: " + tapX + " - Y: " + tapY);
            if (manLocX < (ScreenWidth - littleManWidth))
            {
                manLocX = manLocX + skippingSteps;
                Canvas.SetLeft(littleMan, manLocX);
            }

        }

    }
```

Expected behavior is that on the a tap, system will figure out which side of the screen has been tapped and move the little man to that direction.

```
skippingSteps = 40;
```

When the application starts `setGame()` function runs. the problem i am having is that when the application starts and i tap on the right side of the screen, the littleMan jumps too far out of the right bound of the screen. and when i press left, it starts to come back. With the breakpoints, the data i have collected seems fine but when the `Canvas.SetLeft` or `Canvas.SetTop` is called the littleMan which is a gif image of 20x20 jumps to a location of 520 in the X Plane.

Can someone help me understand what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i solved my issue the following way.

My XAML

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Canvas Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image Name="littleMan" Source="images/smileyFace.gif" Stretch="None"></Image>
    </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

My code behind

```
    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += Game_Loaded;
    }

    void Game_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetGame();
        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap;
        LayoutRoot.ManipulationCompleted += new EventHandler<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(LayoutRoot_ManipulationCompleted);
    }

    void LayoutRoot_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

            switch (gesture.GestureType)
            {
                case GestureType.Tap:
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MoveLittleMan(gesture.Position));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetGame()
    {
        ScreenWidth = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
        ScreenHeight = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;

        // littleman image is in 20 * 20
        littleManWidth = 20;
        littleManHeight = 20; 

        manLocY = (ScreenHeight / 2) + littleManHeight; //vert
        manLocX = (ScreenWidth / 2) + littleManWidth; //hori

        littleMan.Margin = new Thickness(manLocX, manLocY, 0, 0);

        leftControlArea = (ScreenWidth / 2);
        rightControlArea = (ScreenWidth / 2); // answer to the screen width;
        topControlArea = (ScreenHeight / 3);
        bottomControlArea = (ScreenHeight / 3) * 2; // answer to the screen height
    }

    private void MoveLittleMan(Vector2 tappedWhere)
    {
        double tapX, tapY;
        tapX = tappedWhere.X; // represent where user tapped on screen width wise
        tapY = tappedWhere.Y; // represent where user tapped on screen height wise


        if(tapY <= topControlArea)
        {
            // move top
            Debug.WriteLine("Move TOP - X: " + tapX + " - Y: " + tapY);
            if (manLocY > littleManHeight)
            {
                manLocY = manLocY - skippingSteps;
                littleMan.Margin = new Thickness(manLocX, manLocY, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        else if(tapY >= bottomControlArea)
        {
            //move bottom
            Debug.WriteLine("Move BOTTOM - X: " + tapX + " - Y: " + tapY);
            if (manLocY < (ScreenHeight - littleManHeight -50))
            {
                manLocY = manLocY + skippingSteps;
                littleMan.Margin = new Thickness(manLocX, manLocY, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        else if (tapX <= leftControlArea && tapY > topControlArea && tapY < bottomControlArea)
        { 
            //move left
            Debug.WriteLine("Move LEFT - X: " + tapX + " - Y: " + tapY);
            if (manLocX > littleManWidth)
            {
                manLocX = manLocX - skippingSteps;
                littleMan.Margin = new Thickness(manLocX, manLocY, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        else if (tapX > rightControlArea && tapY > topControlArea && tapY < bottomControlArea)
        { 
            //move right
            Debug.WriteLine("Move RIGHT - X: " + tapX + " - Y: " + tapY);
            if (manLocX < (ScreenWidth - littleManWidth))
            {
                manLocX = manLocX + skippingSteps;
                littleMan.Margin = new Thickness(manLocX, manLocY, 0, 0);
            }
        }

    }
```